# Misuse of aggregate function avg()

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a table named recent_grads and it has columns major, sharewomen, where major is a string for example "engineering", "medical" etc. and sharewomen is a float for example "1230.23" etc.

I want to select and filter the rows that are greater than the average value of sharewomen column.

I want to know why this query is not working.

```
SELECT *
FROM recent_grads
WHERE ShareWomen > AVG(ShareWomen);
```

It's currently giving me this error.

> (sqlite3.OperationalError) misuse of aggregate function AVG()
> [SQL: SELECT *  FROM recent_grads WHERE ShareWomen > AVG(ShareWomen);]
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: you can't achieve what you want without subrequest. And aggregating functions are not allowed in the where clause.

Comment: Please tag only the **single** RDBMS you are using, not 4 completely different ones. Please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to find the average over the entire table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM recent_grads
WHERE ShareWomen > (SELECT AVG(ShareWomen) FROM recent_grads);
```

This is straightforward and is what I would recommend.  For a more sophisticated version, you could use `AVG()` as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT r.*, AVG(ShareWomen) OVER () AS AvgShareWomen
    FROM recent_grads r
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE ShareWomen > AvgShareWomen;
```